# How to show your own facebook data on a website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, feed

I got "The question you're asking appears subjective and is likely to be closed." when I started to write my this and a lot of similar titles popped up.

So I've browsed them all and only two might actually help me solve the problem, but they weren't answered.

So... I will continue to ask my question and hope that it wont be closed.

Here it goes:

All I want is to show the feed of a facebook page on a separate website. I.e. status updates, photos, videos, events, comments and likes, all public.

I've googled and also looked at some docs on the facebook developer pages, but all I found was about how to make the visitor grant my fb-app rights to do stuff. Then I would get an access_token which I could use, BUT this token expires.

Never mind... I *DONT* want to make the visitor grant stuff, I only want to show *MY* stuff, which is already public.

Preferably I would like to do it with javascript and ajax. PHP might not be supported where I have my site. So if you have an answer for me please say it in javascript first :)

Although ALL answers are more than welcome.

Please, pretty please, with sugar on top, help me with this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting public data of a facebook page is easy, you don't even have to own the page for that.

You will need a facebook application for that, once you have that you can then authenticate against facebook as the application (from your servers) as explained in the [Authenticating as an App guide](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/). You can try it with a simple curl request to:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
    client_id=YOUR_APP_ID
   &client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET
   &grant_type=client_credentials
```

After you authenticate you receive an app access token and you can use it to make api requests for public data.

For example, try the South Park page [object](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=southpark), [feed connection](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=southpark/feed), [photos connection](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=southpark/photos) and [events connection](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=southpark/photos).
The token used in the graph explorer is a user token, but you can paste there the access token you got from the curl request for example and it will work.

Comment: Ah thanks a lot. What kind of rights does the grant_type=client_credentials give? Are there different grant types?

Comment: That gives you an authenticated channel with facebook basically, you can use that to query for public data. If you want more then you'll have to get a user access token but you don't need it for page data. As for "grant_type", I'm not sure, I think that I only saw it in one more place: [extending client side tokens](http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/). If the answer answers your question, please accept it. thanks